# momentjs - diff() returns wrong time difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to calculate the time until the US/Central midnight. The problem is that my calculation returns 3 hours 30 minutes (as for me in Europe it's 20:30).

```
moment('2020-12-19 23:59:59', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", 'US/Central') - moment.tz('US/Central')
```

I think this should work. I'm calculating a difference between US/Central midnight and US/Central now, but it returns the wrong amount of milliseconds.

Do you know how to make it work?

EDIT:

Tried it with `diff` and still the same result:

```
moment('2020-12-19 23:59:59', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", 'US/Central').diff(moment.tz('US/Central'),'hours')
> 3
```

EDIT2:

Tried `moment().tz` instead of `moment.tz` and it didn't help at all...

```
moment('2020-12-19 23:59:59', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", 'US/Central').diff(moment().tz('US/Central'),'hours')
> 3
```

Comment: Try moment().tz('US/Central') instead

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu Nope, it doesn't work...

Comment: Try setting the default timezone instead of using tz, like this moment.tz.setDefault('US/Central')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try getting the 2 times separately then find another way to check the difference between them. For example

```js
var now = new Date();
var midnight = new Date();

midnight.setHours(0,0,0,0); // this set's the midnight var to exactly midnight at your systems timezone, you can then offset that time after this
```

Then use either moment or some other package to check the difference between the two times.